# How to split a nested column into a few new columns in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In Python, I'm working with a dataset to determine how reactions of users are related to the post reach. My dataset is structured in this way, the Reactions column being nested:

```
   PostID    Reach    Reaction
   01        787767   {"like":49852,"wow":8017,"haha":3200,"anger":3}
   02        973183   {"like":57911,"wow":3013,"haha":8017,"anger":15}
   03        ...      ...
```

I want to restructure the data and create separate reaction columns so the dataframe would be looking like that:

```
   PostID    Reach    like     wow     haha     anger
   01        787767   49852    8017    3200     3
   02        973183   57911    3013    8017     15
   03        ...      ...
```

Comment: Is that a column of JSON or dicts?

Comment: The column is json, thx for the answers. Both worked!

Answer (score 5):

Convert the dictionaries to Pandas `Series`:

```
pd.concat([df.iloc[:,:2], df.Reaction.apply(pd.Series)],axis=1)
#   PostID   Reach  anger  haha   like   wow
#0       1  787767      3  3200  49852  8017
#1       2   97318     15  8017  57911  3013
```

Comment: `apply(pd.Series)` is slow, and won't work if it's JSON data.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Why do you think it's JSON data? Any JSON would become a `dict` before it becomes a part of a `DataFrame`.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ What _is_ JSON data in Python?

Comment: Also, no guarantee that `df.iloc[:,:2]` should work for OP's actual data, `drop` would be better here.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't clear. What I meant to say is that I have reason to believe that it might be a column of strings, is all. Anyway, my answer caters to both situations.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of ways to do this, assuming you have a column of *JSON data*. One simple way is `apply`ing a `json.loads` operation, converting the string to dicts, and then using `DataFrame.from_records`, or `json_normalize` to load it in.

```
v = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df.Reaction.apply(pd.json.loads))
```

Or,

```
v = pd.io.json.json_normalize(df.Reaction.apply(pd.json.loads).tolist())
```

Finally, `concat`enate the result.

```
pd.concat([df.drop('Reaction', 1), v], axis=1)

   PostID   Reach  anger  haha   like   wow
0       1  787767      3  3200  49852  8017
1       2  973183     15  8017  57911  3013
```

---

On the other hand, if you have a column of *dictionaries*, then this should be faster -

```
v = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df.Reaction) 
pd.concat([df.drop('Reaction', 1), v], axis=1)

   PostID   Reach  anger  haha   like   wow
0       1  787767      3  3200  49852  8017
1       2  973183     15  8017  57911  3013
```